# PR Curves in TensorFlow Detection API

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection, tensorboard

Fairly new to tensorflow. I ran the demo notebook in https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/object_detection and then recently ran the `train.py` script on my own data. I got tensorboard up and running and see mAP curves, however when I try to click on the PR curves section it says it's not set up.

Would someone please show me what I need to change to enable PR curves with tensorboard and the object detection api?

Also if someone knows how to add a curve for false positive rate that would be really useful as well.

Comment: Can you please add a screenshot or a more detailed information about where you are getting the "not set up" issue?

Comment: I believe the error was along the lines of "No precision–recall curve data was found", but I can't check easily now since I fixed this by following steps here: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/issues/3081